# Why can this tensor have a T-odd and T-even part at the same time?

Tags: symmetry

[In this paper,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.08364.pdf) the author discusses the following nonlinear response relation:
$$\delta s_a=\alpha_{abc}E_bE_c \tag{1},$$
where $\delta s_a$ represents the spin polarization generated by the current driven by the electric field $E_b/E_c$. In Eq.(1), $E_b/E_c$ are time-reversal-invariant quantities: if $\delta s_a$ is reversed by time-reversal symmetry ($\mathcal{T}$), we conclude that $\alpha_{abc}$ is a T-odd tensor; if $\delta s_a$ is not reversed by time-reversal symmetry, we conclude that $\alpha_{abc}$ is a T-even quantity.

However, in the paper cited before, the author claims
$$\alpha_{abc}=\alpha_{abc}^{even}+\alpha_{abc}^{odd} \tag{2}$$
I don't understand why this partition is legitimate. Is it due to the sign change of $\delta s_{a}$ under time-reversal symmetry being indefinite?

Furthermore, consider the nonlinear current response:
$$j_a=\sigma_{abc}E_bE_c \tag{3}$$
where the current density $j_a$ will change its sign under time-reversal symmetry and the electric field $E_b/E_c$ will remain unchanged under time-reversal symmetry. As a result, we find:
$$\mathcal{T}\sigma_{abc}=-\sigma_{abc}$$
namely, the nonlinear conductivity should be a T-odd tensor. However, [in another paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.127.277201), the author seems to also admit a similar partition:
$$\sigma_{abc}=\sigma_{abc}^{even}+\sigma_{abc}^{odd}$$

How could this be true? The current density is not reversed by time-reversal symmetry? This can not be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is a statement about the particular tensors $\alpha$ and $\sigma$, this is a general result.

##### Tensors as sums of even and odd terms

Suppose we have a tensor $M$, and an operator $\mathcal{T}$ with eigenvalues $\pm 1$ (an *idempotent* operator, e.g. a parity operator). We can always write:

$$
\begin{align}
M &= M + \frac{1}{2}\left(\mathcal{T}M - \mathcal{T}M\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[(M + \mathcal{T}M) + (M - \mathcal{T}M)\right] \tag 1
\end{align}
$$

Consider now the first term, $(M + \mathcal{T}M)$; if we apply $\mathcal{T}$ to it, we get:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{T}(M + \mathcal{T}M) &= (\mathcal{T}M + \mathcal{T}^2M) \\
&= \mathcal{T}M +M \\
&= \left(M + \mathcal{T}M\right)  \tag 2
\end{align}
$$
where we have used the fact that $\mathcal{T}^2=\mathrm{I}$ (the identity), since it is idempotent; i.e. its eigenvalues are all +1 or -1, so the squared eigenvalues are all +1.

Equation $(2)$ shows that $(M + \mathcal{T}M)$ is unchanged when we apply $\mathcal{T}$, so this first term in equation $(1)$ is $\mathcal{T}$-even.

Now we repeat this for the second term in equation $(1)$,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{T}(M - \mathcal{T}M) &= (\mathcal{T}M - \mathcal{T}^2M) \\
&= \mathcal{T}M -M\\
&= -\left(M - \mathcal{T}M\right). \tag 3
\end{align}
$$
Now we see that applying $\mathcal{T}$ has resulted in *minus* what we started with, and therefore this term is $\mathcal{T}$-odd.

Thus, equation $(1)$ expresses the tensor $M$ as a sum of a $\mathcal{T}$-even and a $\mathcal{T}$-odd tensor. At no point have we assumed anything about our tensor $M$, and so this expression holds generally.
$$
\begin{align}
M &= \frac{1}{2}\left(M + \mathcal{T}M\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(M - \mathcal{T}M)\right)\\
&= M^\mathrm{even} + M^\mathrm{odd} \tag 4
\end{align}
$$

##### When $M$ *is* $\mathcal{T}$-even or odd

If the tensor $M$ *does* have a particular $\mathcal{T}$-symmetry, then all that happens is that one of the terms in equation $(4)$ is zero (i.e. either $M^\mathrm{even}=0$ or $M^\mathrm{odd}=0$). For example, if $M$ is $\mathcal{T}$-odd, then $\mathcal{T}M=-M$ and we have:

$$
\begin{align}
M^\mathrm{even} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(M + \mathcal{T}M\right) \\
 &= \frac{1}{2}\left(M + (-M)\right) \\
 &= 0;
\end{align}
$$
and, correspondingly,
$$
\begin{align}
M^\mathrm{odd} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(M - \mathcal{T}M\right) \\
 &= \frac{1}{2}\left(M - (-M)\right) \\
 &= \frac{1}{2}\left(2M\right) \\
 &= M,
\end{align}
$$
which is as expected, since in this example $M$ is $\mathcal{T}$-odd!

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent answer. The parity operator $\mathcal{P}$ works for your partition in Eq.(1), what about the time-reversal operator? I mean $\mathcal{T}^2=-1$ will be obtained for time-reversal symmetry. In addition, is there any reference for the partition in Eq.(1)?

Comment: @Jack to get equation 1, you just add and subtract TM from M; I've edited the answer to show this. For complex Hermitian operators (e.g. time-reversal), I think it's actually T-dagger T you do, so that you still get 1 (|T|^2=1).

Comment: The first paper has the quote: "Note that in nonmagnetic materials, only $\alpha^\text{even}$ exists. The two parts have different symmetry properties. For $\alpha^\text{odd}$ these can be found in
[32]." So at least in this paper, the partition to odd/even isn't just a mathematical trick, but seems to convey a real physical meaning.

Comment: @Tyberius It often does have a physical meaning, but I thought the question was about how such a partitioning is possible without assuming any particular properties.

Comment: @PhilHasnip Hi, bother you again. I understand the partition trick, one is even and the other one is odd. The proof depends on $\mathcal{T}^2=1$, this works for parity symmetry but is not true for the time-reversal operator, which demands $\mathcal{T}^2=-1$, seeing Eq.(14) https://www.its.caltech.edu/~xcchen/img/Ph129b2020/lecture/lecture0312.pdf

Comment: @Jack it works for scalar (non-spinor) states under time-reversal, since T^2=1 then. For spinor states, time-reversal additionally flips the spin, which is why T^2=-1 for fermions. For the partitioning, I think you just do the equivalent trick with spinors, but now you'll need to mix the spinor components to get the required symmetry.

Comment: +10. This is a beautiful answer. Have you seen [this related question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8923/5) also about tensors?